# Is it possible to create a formula that is fulfilling following conditions, using only elementary functions/arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-functions

Conditions:

- Variables: X, L
- if X = L result of the formula should be `-L`
  otherwise it should be `0`

So $$f(X,L)=\begin{cases}-L&X=L\\0&\text X\ne L\end{cases}$$

Is it possible to construct a formula fulfilling these conditions using only elementary arithmetic/functions?

Comment: No, unless you count things like finding the maximum or finding the absolute value as elementary enough.

Comment: If these conditions have some property that makes it impossible, you could point it out and post it as an answer :) .

Comment: The answer with max/abs as "the best one can get" would be also great.

Comment: On second thought max and abs may not be enough since those functions are continuous and yours is not.

Answer (score 0):

How about $$-L\delta_{ (X, L)}$$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker $\delta$ function?

Or if that is not elementary enough: $$-L\lim_{ t \to L} \frac {t-L}{t-X}$$